# Diagnosing WinForms Databinding problem

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net

I'm learning Databinding from here http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_databinding.html

I'm just updating the dataset and then updating the sql database using sqlDataAdaper.Update();

```
    this.selectCommand = new SqlCommand();
    this.selectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    this.selectCommand.Connection = this.connection;

    this.dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(this.selectCommand);
    this.dataAdapter.MissingSchemaAction = System.Data.MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;

    this.commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(this.dataAdapter);
    this.selectCommand.CommandText = "Select `FirstName`,`lastname` from customers where customerId=123";
    this.dataAdapter.Fill(this.dataSet, "customers");
```

now binding as:

```
// Simple Data Binding
txtBox.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", this.dataSet, "Customers.FirstName", true));
```

Its showing the firstname and when I change the first name and hit save button following code runs:

```
    this.dataAdapter.Update(this.dataSet, "customers");
```

changed value is not reflected in the dataset and thus not in the  database too. I don't understand why?

When will the BindingContext push the value that I changed in Textbox (GUI) into the dataset?
Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On clicking save button do this:

```
   CurrencyManager  cm = (CurrencyManager)this.BindingContext[dataSet, "customers"];
   cm.EndCurrentEdit();
   this.dataAdapter.Update(this.dataSet, "customers");
```